Webform confirmation popup not displaying for custom template
I have a webform and I need to show a confirmation message in a popup. I enabled this option in the settings.


I am using a custom template for the webform as suggested in twig.
But after submitting the form it's not displaying the popup.
When taking the form only from the webforms list from admin it is displaying the popup. It is using the default template web/modules/contrib/webform/templates/webform.html.twig at that time.
What am I missing here?
My custom webform template (webform--register-your-interest-campaigns.html.twig) is as follows:
<div class="form-section">
    <form{{ attributes }}>
        {{ title_prefix }}
        {{ element.elements.form_token }}
        {{ element.elements.form_build_id }}
        {{ element.elements.form_id }}
        {{ element.elements.uc }}

        <div class="row footer-form-row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 form-col">
                {{ element.elements.first_name }}
                {{ element.elements.first_name.status_messages }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 form-col">
                {{ element.elements.last_name }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 form-col">
                {{ element.elements.email }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 form-col">
                {{ element.elements.country_code }}
                {{ element.elements.phone }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 form-col">
                {{ element.elements.bed_enquired_for }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 form-col  formCheckBox ">
                {{ element.elements.agree_privacy }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12 ">
                {{ element.elements.time_spent }}
                {{ element.elements.captcha }}
                {{ element.form_token }}
                {{ element.form_build_id }}
                {{ element.form_id }}
                {{ element.elements.actions }}
                {% if element.status_messages %}
                  {{ element.status_messages }}
                {% endif %}
                {{ title_suffix }}
            </div>

        </div>


        </form>
</div>


What is the difference between your temple and the default one? Add that to the question. Also indicate the front end theme. I’m guessing Bootstrap.

See also https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3402366

@monalisa in the default template  only children given {{ title_prefix }}
{{ children }}
{{ title_suffix }}. So as you see we can't do any styling to individual form elements

Yes. the issue you mentioned is very close to what i am getting. As far as i understand , the maintainer says its hard to override default rendering with popup with a custom template. Although let me try the 6.x dev version as he tagged for that change

You should use the current version. Older versions are not maintained.

Yea i was using 6.2 though
